# Symfony Twig path() not working when using render

Tags: symfony, layout, path, twig, render

I have a layout that includes some chuck of code form a controller called "Layout"

In the header section I have:

```
{% block accessinfo %} {% render "/layout/accessinfo" %} {% endblock %}
```

It works pretty fine, the view file content is:

```
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    {% if( is_logged == 0 ) %}
        Welcome, access your <a id="accessAccount" title="Access your account">here</a>.
    {% else %}
        Hi, <b><em> {{ is_logged_user_name }}</em></b>, <a id="doLogout" href="javascript:void;">(Logout)</a>. 
       <i class="icon-user"></i> <a href="{{path('account/manage')}}">Your Account</a>    
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

As one can figure out, path('account/manage') points to the Route named 'account/manage', but it's not returning the fully qualified URL to my project.

It returns:

```
http://localhost.project/account/manage
```

where it should be:

```
http://localhost.project/web/app_dev.php/account/manage
```

***NOTE:** I have path() all around my template files and they work like a charm.*

**IMPORTANT:** I found out that when I call REQUEST URI inside the action method:

`$this->get('request')->server->get('REQUEST_URI')`

PHP will return the URL called by the render, in this case is:

```
/layout/accessinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm not fully understanding your issue but it seems like you missunderstood the use of the `path()` and `render()` functions.

First of all if you like to render a controller and you follow the [documentation here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) you would do it like this...

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles') }}
{# with some parameters #}
{{ render(controller('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles', {
    'max': 3
})) }}
```

This assumes you're using Symfony >= 2.2. This follows the **bundle:controller:action** pattern, which is called [Controller Naming Pattern](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#controller-naming-pattern)

For a normal use of the `path()` function you would always use the **name** of the route and not a hardcoded URL (as it seems like you're passing in URLs and not route names?)

Let's say your route is called `accountmanager`, your `routing.yml` should look like this example

```
# app/config/routing.yml
accountmanager:
    path:      /account/manage
    defaults:  { _controller:YourBundleName:YourControllerName:ControllerAction }
```

And with that in your `routing.yml` in twig the use of `path()` is simply achieved by writing  `{{ path('accountmanager') }}`

See the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-pages) on this topic. Using the name of the route and not a URL pattern ensures that you're getting to the right page which also includes your environment settings (like `app_dev.php` for your `dev` environment)

Comment: I am using path('account/manage') which is the route name. It works for other files loaded via render.

Comment: I am using Annotations. Also changed the route name to "account" and changed the render usage to "{{ render(controller('MySiteBundle:Layout:accessInfo', { 'max': 3 })) }}" but it continues rendering "localhost/account"

Comment: How do they look like? I'm not sure why this problem is occuring. But unfortunately I never used `{% render %}` in the way you seem to do it. Normally `path()` always outputs the correct URL...any errors etc?